# Enableing Line Smoothing causes axes drawing errors

Tags: matlab, plot

In Matlab 2011a I am plotting a line, and I use the parameter `("LineSmoothing", 1)` to make the line look prettier, but it causes the Y and X axis to disappear.

[image]

Does someone know what is causing this, and more importantly, how it can be fixed?

I tried the `opengl('OpenGLLineSmoothingBug',1)` but it didn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `LineSmoothing` is an undocumented/unsupported feature probably because its buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The undocumented [`LineSmoothing`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/plot-linesmoothing-property/) property causes the figure to automatically switch to using the OpenGL renderer. And the bug you've shown in fact affects all OpenGL-rendererd figures (regardless of this property use).

Example: (tested on R2012a in WinXP)

```
plot(1:10,'o-'), box on
set(gcf, 'Renderer','opengl')
```

[image: screenshot]

note how the top and right borders of the box disappear once you execute the second line.

There are some [suggested](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5TS5P4/index.html) [workarounds](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-5X41G7/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the alternatives!